# How to prove that every instance of the axiom $P\to(Q\to P)$ is a tautology?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Bellow is what I tried. I think that's enough to prove that $P\to(Q\to P)$ is a tautology, but I'm not sure if that's enough to show that every instance of it is a tautology as well.

$P\to(Q\to P)$

$\equiv (\neg P \lor (Q\to P))$ (elimination of $\to$)

$\equiv (\neg P \lor (\neg Q \lor P))$ (elimination of $\to$)

$\equiv (\neg Q \lor (P \lor \neg P))$ (associativy)

$\equiv (\neg Q \lor T)$

$\equiv T$

Comment: you can write down truth tables if you want but the point of a proof like you’ve written is exactly that it covers all cases.

Comment: To show something is a tautology in classical propositional logic, you can just write out a truth table with P and Q representing arbitrary propositions. 

I'm not sure what you mean "show that every instance of it is an axiom as well". Its either assumed as an axiom schema that P --> (Q --> P) or it isn't. But you don't need to show this

Comment: sorry, this was I mistake. I actually meant "show that every instance of it is a **tautology** as well"

Comment: 1. (Referring to the title) is it relevant that the formula is an axiom? 2. What's an *instance* of an axiom/formula?

Comment: Implication introduction: If (assuming $Q$) we're able to derive $P$, then $Q\to P$ holds. With this in mind: Assuming $P$, we derive $P$ trivially, and thus follows $Q\to P$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed by cases:

1. Assume $P$ is true.

Since $P$ is true, $Q → P$ is true by the truth table definition of "$\rightarrow$". Therefore, $P → (Q → P)$ is also true.

2. Assume $P$ is false.

Then $P → (Q → P)$  is true, again by the definition of "$\rightarrow$".

So $P → (Q → P)$ is true in either case. Therefore, it is a tautology.